# get a bs4.BeautifulSoup by .children?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The `.children` method returns a **Python list** (see last line of included code) whereas I want something soupy; if I could get a bs4.BeautifulSoup object could run `find` and other operations on the children.

A `bs4.BeautifulSoup` seems like the only object that can contain sibling tags.  How do I get a soupy data structure with the children?

```
In [123]: a._soup
Out[123]: 
<div guppy-html="no-posts">There are <i>literally</i> no posts to show you</div>
<div><p guppy-html="text"></p></div>

In [120]: type(a._soup)
Out[120]: bs4.BeautifulSoup

In [129]: list(a._soup.children)
Out[129]: 
[<div guppy-html="no-posts">There are <i>literally</i> no posts to show you</div>,
 u'\n',
 <div><p guppy-html="text"></p></div>]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "soupy"? As far as I understand, every element inside `.children` is either a `Tag`, or `NavigableString`.

Comment: @alecxe He wants something alone the lines of `soup.children.find`. But that doesn't work because you get `listiterator` instead.

Comment: I believe what you're *trying* to do is filter tags in layers. For example, you want to find all the divs first, and then you want to find all the divs that have a class of `containter` for example. Is this the case, if so then please wait for my answer.

Comment: `a beautiful soup of children` wrong no matter how I read it.